# How to split() a String while maintaining whitespace

Tags: java, regex

How do you split a string of words and retain whitespaces?

Here is the code:

```
String words[] = s.split(" ");
```

String s contains: `hello  world`

After the code runs, words[] contains: `"hello"` `""` `world`

Ideally, it should not be an empty string in the middle, but contain both whitespaces: words[] should be: `"hello"` `" "` `" "` `world`

How do I get it to have this result?

Comment: Why you don't want to trim your string?

Comment: Because I need to keep it verbatim what the user inputs. It's part of the specs.

Comment: `String.split` removes the delimiter you provide to it (the space in this case). If you want a different behavior, you'd have to implement a variant of `split` yourself.

Comment: @Chronio, existing api can support it. why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions:

```
String[] words = "hello  world".split("((?<=\\s+)|(?=\\s+))");
```

where `(?<=\\s+)` and `(?=\\s+)` are zero-width groups.

Answer (score 10):

If you can tolerate both white spaces together in one string, you can do

```
String[] words = s.split("\\b");
```

Then words contains `("hello", "  ", "world")`.

Comment: +1 because in my case, this also would have been acceptable, because I was ultimately trying to reverse each word's characters, but leave the words in order and keep the same whitespace in between each word.

Comment: OMG - this just made my entire day. Have been struggling to split words and retain spaces in between. So many workarounds that didn't work 100% - and then I see this - and everything falls into place!

Comment: This is the best!! +1

Answer (score 4):

`s.split("((?<= )|(?= ))");` is one way.

Technically, the *regular expression* is using lookahead and lookbehind. The single space after each `=` is the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
int rangeStart = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
  if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
    if (rangeStart < i) {
      result.add(s.substring(rangeStart, i));
    }
    result.add(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)));
    rangeStart = i + 1;
  }
}
if (rangeStart < s.length()) {
  result.add(s.substring(rangeStart));
}
```

Yeah, no regexes, sue me. This way you can see how it works more easily.

Comment: I tested this out, and I can attest that it works.