# Java Include delimiter into splitted array

Tags: java, arrays, regex

Is there a way in `Java` in which I can `split` a string into an array, but with the `delimiter`? For example normally I would have a `String` such as this in the text editor I am building:

```
String content = "What time\nWhat day\nWhat month\n\n\nAsdf"
```

And if I called the `split` method with the \n `delimiter` like this:

```
content.split("\n")
```

I would get a `String[] array` like this:

```
{"What time", "What day", "What month", "Asdf"}
```

But I want this:

```
{"What time", "\n", "What day", "\n", "What month", "\n", "\n" ....}
```

Is there any **built-in property I need to set** or do I have to implement this from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried adding an extra slash in the variable? e.g. 'What time\\n'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273020/how-to-split-a-string-while-maintaining-whitespace

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951850/split-string-with-regex-but-keep-delimeters-in-match-array

Comment: [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, one of them is: "after splitting using separator, add separator after each element except last one like this":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "sawad";
        String seperator="a";
        String[] s=content.split(seperator);
        int length=s.length;
        System.out.println(length);
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }


        String [] d=new String[(length * 2) -1];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            d[2*i]=s[i];
            if(i<length-1)
                d[2*(i+1) -1]=seperator;
        }

        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println(d.length);
        for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(d[i]);
        }
    }
```